# How to pass environment variables from helmfile values.yaml to chart's values.yaml?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helmfile

I have a helmfile release with multiple charts. There are values.yaml inside each chart. Рow to make values inside those values.yaml ​​change depending on environment? I know how to parameterize helmfile's values.yaml, but I can't find any way to throw those values further into the charts values.yaml. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized that helmfiles values.yaml it's just a source for helm --values. No special actions should be done.

Answer (score 1):

If you name a values file `anything.yaml.gotmpl`, then Helmfile will apply its templating to that file before using it as values to install the relevant chart.

So if your `helmfile.yaml` says

```yaml
environments:
  prod:
    values:
      - domain: prod.example.com
releases:
  - name: a-service
    namespace: a-service
    chart: ./a-service/charts/a-service
    values:
      - ./a-service/charts/a-service/values.yaml.gotmpl # <-- *.gotmpl filename
```

then the `values.yaml.gotmpl` can have

```yaml
service:
  annotations:
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: >-
      a-service.{{ .Values.domain }}
{{/* Expression    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   uses per-environment values */}}
```

and you can install this with

```sh
helmfile -e prod apply
```